# Hooked up new programmable timer, but concerned about red wire

Tags: wiring

Ok so I hooked up the new switch its a Defiant Model # 49814 purchased from Home Depot and I have another question, the red wire when tested with the NCVT is registering high voltage along with the black wire connected to the other black wire is that correct? Did I do it right? The capped red wire just concerns me, is it supposed to have power? If so should it be capped or hooked up to another wire?
[image]
[image]

Comment: It looks like that red wire is to connect more than one timer in parallel, but knowing the manufacturer/model number would be helpful in confirming that.

Answer (score 1):

The switch you installed can be wired for either single pole or 3-way configurations. The red wire is a traveller for the 3-way setup. It is not used in the single pole setup. Capping it is right.